# Add more fields on media attachments uploaded in the dashboard

Tags: uploads

Is it possible to extend, or add more field when using WordPress browser uploader ?

`var_dump($_POST)` return 3 field, I wish to add more :

```
array (size=3)
  'action' => string 'upload-attachment' (length=17)
  'name' => string 'file.jpg' (length=8)
  '_wpnonce' => string 'abcde12345' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like, you can add additional values using `plupload_default_params` filter hook.

Example usage

```
add_filter( 'plupload_default_params', function( $params ) : array {
    $params['some'] = 'some'; 
    return $params;
});
```

Comment: 'some' is hardcoded, is possible to put dynamic content in it? For example `$params['some'] = $_POST` ? I tried and it return false.

Comment: not sure what you wan t to add, but depending on when you hook the above filter, you can add params to the attachment that are linked to its parent post.  See this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184557/do-attachments-added-to-custom-post-types-have-a-post-parent#answer-195004)